# persist react data in react after page change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, cookies, local-storage

I am using react and everytime after navigating away from a page, the state goes back to original state. I have a state that is set when a user clicks on a button. This handles the setState of `listView` which is a boolean. So if listView is true, then the view would be listView and vice versa. The issue is that if I choose the other view, and refresh the page, immediately after it would go back to listView. Now I saw how to persist state using hooks by doing some research but I couldnt find an example of doing this in a class component that really is similar to my example. Please see my code. Thanks!

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listView: true,
    };
  }
```

And the toggle area that setStates of the listView to be true or false, not really necessary, but just in case:

```
 <ToggleButtonGroup className={classes.toggleButtonContainer} exclusive orientation="horizontal">
       <ToggleButton className={listView ? classes.selectedToggleButton : '' } selected={listView} onClick={() => this.setState({ listView: true })} value="list" aria-label="list">
         <Icon fontSize="large" color="default">view_list</Icon>
                </ToggleButton>
                <ToggleButton className={!listView ? classes.selectedToggleButton : '' } selected={!listView} onClick={() => this.setState({ listView: false })} value="module" aria-label="module">
                  <Icon fontSize="large" color="default">view_module</Icon>
                </ToggleButton>
         </ToggleButtonGroup>
```

Comment: See also [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) as easier & lower levels of entry than full-blown app management systems like `react-redux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with different methods:

1. [React-Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) , alternative [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)
2. [Redux Persist Example](https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/redux-persist-how-it-works-and-how-to-change-the-structure-of-your-persisted-store)
3. Adding and Fetching state value from `localStorage` like this:

   ```
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
         listView: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('listView')) || []
       }
     }

    renderListView = (selection) => {
         ...

         this.setState({
           listView: selection
         },() => {
           localStorage.setItem('listView', JSON.stringify(this.state.listView))
         });
       }
   ```
4. Pushing into URL as query param after every response change:

   ```
   history.push({pathname: 'path/', search: '?' + Qs.stringify(params)});

   //fetch the params from URL
   params = Qs.parse(nextProps.location.search.substring(1));

   //add it to your local state of particular component
   this.setState({selectedOption: params.selectedOption});
   ```